# Meteor - How can i notify other session

Tags: meteor

I am coding a basic meteor app and I ask myself how to notify other session of a change.

I have a basic template showing details of a document.
And someone can delete this document,
How can I notify other session that was watching this document, that it was deleted and redirect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your document is in a collection and the delete corresponds to removing the document from the collection, you can use Meteor's [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) on the collection to register a callback when the document you're watching is removed:

```
Documents.find({_id: myDocumentId}).observe({
  removed: function () {
    console.log('document removed');
  }
});
```

and from there do any DOM/Session manipulation you want to notify clients of the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you display your document by accessing directly your collection client-side (i.e. you don't use a method), your page fields values should reactively disappear since the document does not exist anymore.

What you can do is add a field `deleted` to your document and when it changes to `true`, you display your notification. I would advise to use something like a modal, so the user cant dodge it (when he close it, you redirect).

It also means that instead of deleting a document, the other user just change its `deleted` field to `true`. Once you set it to `true` you can also set a time differed function to effectively delete the doc for example 5mn later:

```
 Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    Document.remove(yourDocumentID);
  }, 300000)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the method setInterval, i was thinking about doing it like this (with a flag on the document), but i was wonder if there was an other way, like catching some sort of event on the other session ...

Comment: I am sure there is another way (like always), and I would be curious to know how. However, it what seemed to me the easiest way.